# Do Star Tokens roll over to next year?

Tags: stardew-valley

First year of play here. I don't particularly want to grind mini games to get the 2000 token prize. If I don't turn in my tokens this year, will I still have them for next year's fair?

Comment: You should also know, you can buy tokens.  First year I'm not sure if you'd have enough to do so, but not hard to do by any other year.

Comment: Pro tip: the betting game is rigged 3:1 towards green!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the star tokens do not carry over to the next year's fair. Whatever you don't spend this year will just disappear.

It is worth knowing that you will be awarded a number of tokens according to the place you've scored in the showcase, ranging from 50 tokens for last place to 1000 tokens for first place. Since the festival doesn't automatically end once you start the showcase, you can see how many tokens you win from it before grinding away at the mini-games.

Comment: Well, looks like I'm going to have to grind either way!

Comment: The wiki says you don't have to grind:  http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Stardew_Valley_Fair on the "Spin the Wheel" game, green has a 75%+ chance.  Continue making safe, small bets on green and you can get up to 3400 (enough for all the items) fairly quickly.

Comment: Its not that bad of a grind - if you're decent at fishing, it can take as few as four rounds at that game to get the other thousand points. (I've never done it in 4 shots, but catching 7 fish, all of them perfect, rewards 260+ points, and I've done that, just not 4 times in a row).